# Clarification for example 3.4. in Palka's Introduction to Complex Function Theory

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

In page 24 Palka discusses the following example

> Show that the function $f(z) = (1 - z)/(1 + z)$ maps the disk $D = \{z: |z| < 1\}$ onto the half-plane $H = \{w: \mathrm{Re}(w) > 0\}$.
> Steps: Set $w = f(z)$ and rewrite $w$ in the following manner: for $z = x + iy$, $w = \frac{1 - z}{1 + z} = \frac{1 - z}{1 + z}\cdot \frac{1 + \bar{z}}{1 + \bar{z}} = \frac{(1 - |z|^2) - 2yi}{|1 + z|^2}$ from which we read off the relationship $\mathrm{Re}(w) = \frac{1 - |z|^2}{|1 + z|^2}$, which makes it evident that $w$ belongs to $H$ for $z$ in $D$. We infer that $f(D)$ is contained in $H$. Does every point of $H$ belong to $f(D)$? To answer this, fix $w$ in $H$ and solve the equation $w = (1 - z)/(1 + z)$ for $z$ in terms of $w$. The solution is $z = (1 - w)/(1 + w)$. By construction $w = f(z)$, so **the above remark shows that $z$ lies in $D$**. Therefore $f(D) = H$.

As a remark, the author does not provide any explicit remark. In any case, my question is is that how can you deduce from $z = (1 - w)/(1 + w)$ that $|z| < 1$ immediately? The only way I can argue about the modulus of $z$ is by taking the modulus of $(1 - w)/(1 + w)$, expanding it, and showing that it is necessarily less than $1$. But the author makes it seem that this is evident by some other means (which he does not elaborate any further).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$|1-w|=\sqrt {(1-x)^{2}+y^{2}} <\sqrt {(1+x)^{2}+y^{2}}=|1+w|$ if $w=x+iy$ and $x >0$.